# MySQL Query - Any issues in this?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, exists

Do you see any issues with this MySQL query? It does not execute.
Any other better ideas?

```
INSERT INTO registration 
   ( m_ID,  e_ID,   STATUS) 
SELECT 
   :m_ID, :e_ID, 1
WHERE 
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE ID = :e_ID)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tablec WHERE m_ID = :m_ID)
```

Passing array with values for `e_id` and `m_ID` (PDO)

Basically the goal is to check if both IDs exists in different tables before inserting onto another table.

**ERROR:**

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL    
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right  
syntax to use near 'WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE ID = '276') AND EX' at 
line 4
```

Comment: Vote to close.  please be more specific about your question.  I see 4,123 issues with your query.  Which ones concern you?

Comment: Tell me ONE issue with that query? Why is it NOT executing?

Comment: @KevinRave: Tell us ONE error message. Posting your PHP code would also help a lot.

Comment: Your error message doesn't correspond to the query you posted.

Comment: Try running just that subquery by itself, first with that value 276, then with the array. Do those both work independently?

Comment: @MarkByers: Do not try to match up the line numbers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if both IDs exists in different tables

Yet your query searches `tableb` twice. Unless you really meant "in a single different table" (and I don't think so, you'd have used a single `EXISTS`), then this might be the error you wanted.

Also, PDO should have some sort of error logging. The query might not execute, but the reason should appear - or it should be possible to make it appear - *somewhere*.

**UPDATE**

I'm afraid I was wrong, the syntax is *not* correct. MySQL doesn't allow `SELECT ... WHERE` unless a table is specified.

Try changing

```
SELECT 
   :m_ID, :e_ID, 1
WHERE EXISTS
```

in

```
SELECT * FROM
   ( SELECT :m_ID, :e_ID, 1 ) AS dummy
WHERE EXISTS
```

*TEST*:

```
mysql> SELECT 42;
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 42 WHERE true;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE true' at line 1


mysql> SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 42 ) AS answer WHERE true;
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. The 2nd select is for tablec

Comment: Okay. Yet, you should have a way of recovering PDO's last error. What does `errorInfo()` say?

Comment: (the code as it is should work; tableb does have a column called ID and not e_ID, right? And again, tablec's id is called m_ID and not ID?)

Comment: The field names in the SQL are correct.

Comment: You nailed it. But still doesn't explain why it did not work as it is.

Comment: @KevinRave: It's just the way MySQL works. Read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)! The allowed syntax is shown, and there's no valid syntax which allows a `WHERE` clause without a `FROM` clause. Just because you *want* it to be allowed doesn't mean that it is allowed.

Comment: Well, it did not work because the query was incorrect. It had a syntax error, so PDO didn't execute it. There might be an use in a FROM-less `WHERE` (I thought it should work too - had to see the error to convince myself), but MySQL thinks otherwise, so...

Answer (score 0):

You said that you "are looking to check IDs from different tables",

currently you are checking the same tables twice:

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE ID = :e_ID)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE m_ID = :m_ID)
```

maybe you should change the second reference to tableb to become tablec, as in:

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE ID = :e_ID)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tablec WHERE m_ID = :m_ID)
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I actually meant. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have confused the column name with the array names? Could changing it to this code work?

(notice m_ID is now just ID)

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE ID = :e_ID)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tablec WHERE ID = :m_ID)
```

**Based on your new Error edit, this is probably more likely**
or (ID is now e_ID)

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tableb WHERE e_ID = :e_ID)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tablec WHERE m_ID = :m_ID)
```

Comment: Nope. The column names are correct. I rechecked.